# Need some advice to optimize an Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have two applications : the first one inserts data in the table *MyTable*. The second one reads the rows of the table *MyTable* in chunks : let's say 1000 rows per read. This second app must read the data in chronological order, and use a query similar to :

```
SELECT
    C1,
    C2
FROM
(
    SELECT
        rownum AS RowNumber, 
        C1, 
        C2
    FROM
        MyTable
    WHERE
        C3 = :C3
        AND IsProcessed = 0
    ORDER BY
        Timestamp
) temp 
WHERE 
    temp.RowNumber <= 1000
```

The query works, but it is slow (more than one minute, usually it takes only a few seconds to execute) when a lot of not processed rows (for example 10 millions) are waiting in the table *MyTable*. I suppose this is normal, because Oracle must first sort all the concerned rows in the chronological order...
So my question is : is there a better way to write this query ?

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, you do have appropriate indexes on `IsProcessed` and `Timestamp` columns?

Comment: Yes, the appropriate indexes exist.

Comment: "it is slow when a lot of ..." Define "slow" and "a lot".  Your query looks reasonable, but what amt of data are we talking about?  Also, are you doing soft deletes? (isProcessed).

Comment: Can you provide an execution plan? Who updates `IsProcessed` and do they commit often? Note that in long-running batch processes, selecting from tables with long UNDO/REDO logs (few commits after large writes) may cause a lot of load in Oracle

Comment: @Lukas Elder : the second app, after it processed its rows, commits the datas and updates the field IsProcessed. I will update my question to provide an execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your execution plan, I'm guessing that your predicate `C3 = :C3` is quite costly. You should try to optimise that by avoiding `RAW` types. There are several options:

- Ensure you have an index on `SUBCONTRACTID`
- Try adding a function-based index on `NVL(BUSINESSTRANSACTIONID, HEXTORAW('00'))`
- Ensure you have an index on `BUSINESSTRANSACTIONID` and query that using `IS NULL`, rather than `NVL(...)`
- If you can relax the underlying business requirement, it would of course help to remove the `ORDER BY timestamp` clause and process records in arbitrary order.

Apart from that, your query seems fine.

Also, try applying a [`/*+FIRST_ROWS(1000)*/`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/hintsref.htm) hint, as it seems that this isn't done automatically for some reason in your query, even with `ROWNUM` filtering

Comment: My applications are written in .NET, and I must (no choice :( ) use GUIDs as primary key... This is why I have some RAW columns. To answer your questions : 1) I have an index on the column SubcontractId. 2) OK, I'll try that tomorrow. 3) I have an index on BusinessTransactionId. But if I use "IS NULL", Oracle does a full scan... 4) I cannot relax the requirements :(   I will also try the hint you suggested. Thank you ! I think I will accept your answer tomorrow.

Comment: @schglurps: Yes, it looks more tricky than it seemed at first. I'm not very used to using `RAW` types, but you may just try your luck replacing `RAW` by an appropriate `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2` type... Although, that's just a wild guess...

Comment: I tried the function based index and the hint you suggested, this seems to slightly improve the performance of the query. My applications must process a large amount of data, maybe this bottleneck points out I have to improve their architecture. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
  (    SELECT C1, C2
      FROM MyTable
     WHERE C3 = :C3
       AND IsProcessed = 0
     ORDER BY Timestamp
  ) WHERE rownum <= 1000;
```

Try this query.

Comment: That will produce wrong results. `ROWNUM` may be evaluated before other predicates...

Comment: This will not work, because Oracle will only order 1000 rows, and not all the rows in the table...

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to define a column for RowNumber:

```
SELECT C1, C2 
FROM (
   SELECT C1, C2     
   FROM   MyTable
   WHERE  C3 = :C3
      AND IsProcessed = 0
   ORDER BY Timestamp 
   ) temp
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000
```

The only way to make it "faster" would be to somehow further restrict the size of the derived table.